# Is it a best practice to store csv test data files in the git repo?

Tags: csv, github

In a microservice we have to validate an incoming csv file. To perform such validations multiple csv files with different test data are stored in github repo along with the code . These files are used for different test cases. Which of the below two can be considered as engineering best practice.

1. Storing test data in multiple csv files in git repo and the same shall be used for testing.
2. Other option is to put the data content in java test files as strings in Test folder and at run time create csv file and use it for testing.

Your suggestions and inputs are appreciated.

Stored test data in multiple csv files in git repo and the same was used for testing, but as the use cases increases number of test csv files increases as well, hence it is not clear if this is in accordance with the engineering best practice.

Comment: Perhaps a better fit at https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: You can do both but the first option is more widespread